# Manually Open custom inspector for serializable object

Tags: unity3d-editor, unity-game-engine

I have a window editor that holds nodes. I would like to open a custom inspector when one of these nodes is selected. The node class is a custom serializable class. Is this possible?.

It seems that custom inspectors can be created manually through the Editor.CreateEditor method but can't see how to let it appear docked like an usual inspector in the unity inspector window.

I would like to achieve the same behaviour that we have when we select a gameobject in sceneview that inmediately show properties for the object (Components, etc...) in the unity inspector.

Cheers

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what your node editor looks like? I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't. I'm still building logic layer. But the question is just that... If I have an editor window is there any possibility to show in unity inspector window the inspector for a given type? In my case, I have a class node and I would like to show the Custom node inspector when I click a node in my Editor window as Unity does when you click in a gameobject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm not sure what you're asking, here are multiple different solutions;

### Selection

If you just want your nodes to become the focus of the hierarchy, then in your custom window's OnGUI method, use the code below;

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(NodeManager))]
public class NodeManager : EditorWindow
{
    private static  NodeManager window;
    private         Node[]      m_nodes;

    [MenuItem("Custom Windows/Node Inspector")]
    public static void Init()
    {
        if(window == null)
            window = GetWindow<NodeManager>("Node Manager", true, typeof(SceneView));
    }

    public void OnGUI()
    {
        m_nodes = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Node>();

        foreach(Node node in m_nodes)
        {
            GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            {
                GUILayout.Label(node.name);
                if (GUILayout.Button("Select"))
                    Selection.objects = new Object[] { node.gameObject };
            }
            GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        }
    }
}
```

This adds a Button for each object in your custom window view, that will then select that object in the hierarchy.

### Auto-Docking

I originally found the second response to [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/16554/docking-editorwindow.html) question, which goes into the details of parameters of the GetWindow method, and with this you can clearly see how to dock the window (I've converted it from JS to C# below).
(I looked fairly extensively in `UnityEditor` and `UnityEditorInternal` namespaces but couldn't find the Hierarchy or the Inspector).

```
GetWindow<T>(string title, bool focus, params System.Type[] desiredDockNextTo)
```

Which we can write for this example as;

```
EditorWindow.GetWindow<NodeInspector>("Node Test", true, typeof(SceneView));
```

This example docks the windows next to the SceneView window. This functionality can be combined with a custom inspector's OnInspectorGUI method, to automatically launch the custom node window, [if it's not already open](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/523839/find-out-if-an-editor-window-is-open.html).

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(Node))]
public class NodeInspector : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();
        NodeManager.Init();
    }
}
```

Sorry if this isn't what you are looking for, if it's not then please give more details and I will amend my answer to better suit the question.
Hope this helped.

Comment: I have upvoted because you took the time to bring a lot of information to the post but this i snot what I'm looking for. I can as you stated, draw an inspector over my editor window. But I want to use the built-in inspector window (the one unity uses) for that.

Comment: Does your node manager just contain the list of node classes, but instead of viewing the details of this script in the same window as the node manager, you want them in a separate window?

Answer (score 1):

Has a possibility, you can make a custom ScriptableObject and Custom Editor for It, and when open the node inspector, just find a instance of the scriptable object and use Selection.selectedObject = scriptableObject, and in the custom editor, make a static field called 'editor' to draw inside.
It will work.